# здравствуйте у меня винда 10, подскажите, что лучше использовать для эмулятора работы yacc и lex

Tags: lex, yacc

здравствуйте у меня винда 10, подскажите, что лучше использовать для эмулятора работы yacc  и lex

Comment: зачем использовать эмуляторы, если можно использовать программы напрямую?

Comment: Если вы реально хотите через эмулятор Линукса, поставьте себе [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Ну или [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), если почему-то WSL не поднялся. Но это не должно быть нужно, lex/yacc (или flex/bison) доступны и под Windows.